# Using jquery.VideoBG to have video as div background – How can I have multiple videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jquery.videoBG](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/) to have a video as a div's background. I was wondering if it was possible to have multiple videos so that each time they visit the page it's a different video as the background.

The below code is what decides the video for the div's background:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').videoBG({
        mp4:'video/header.mp4',
        ogv:'video/header.ogv',
        webm:'video/header.webm',
        poster:'images/poster.jpg',
        scale:true,
        zIndex:0,
        width:'100%',
        height:'740px'
});
})
</script>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to edit that code above to have multiple video sources. Maybe have multiple of the above code (each with a different video) and on page load it only executes one of them at random?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about jquery.videoBG however, you can use the http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/ and play series of random playlist of background video http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-ambient-loop.html

hope that help.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried to work with BigVideo but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work in a div with a fixed height, only the entire page.